# I am not able to add ref to a react bootstrap modal. I am getting error related to " ref.current.click();"

Tags: react-hooks, modal-dialog, ref, react-bootstrap4-modal

```js
const updateNote = (currentNote) => {
        ref.current.click();
        console.log("hey I am the Modal Key");
      };
```

this is the code where I am using the ref , passing this "updateNote" as a prop to Modal component.
please refer to the attached link for complete code
"https://github.com/app-casting/iNotebook-"

I tried `useEffect` hook, but that also I am not able to use here.

Comment: We'll need more code than this in order to fully replicate your issue, a link to the repo is ok but replicating the issue in the question is required. However it's worth noting that `ref.current` can equal `null` and therefore `click` will not be accessible (and therefore not work)

Comment: hey , the issue has been resolved. Earlier I was using a separate component for modal. then I made a change with directly inserting the modal to the same component where my updateNote function is defined. also I was passing ref as a prop, which didn't really worked out. The issue is resolved, but not in a way  I wanted it to resolve. If you still intrested with the issue please visit the repo. Thank You for your interest in the query

Comment: Oh that's good, in that case either close the question or write an answer (and set that as the accepted answer, which you may have to wait a day or so to do) to help future readers